# order a table based on another column attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, relational-database

Ok so in my rails project I have these models: `pools`, `memberships`, and `week_scores`

Pool `has_many :memberships`
Membership `has_many :week_scores`
WeekScore also has an attribute `week:integer` that tells what week it is. That way I know if that table is of week 1 or week 6, etc.
WeekScore has an attribute `score:integer` where I save the points of each user. This makes me think I should change my model name to week_points...

Anyways, I want to show a table of all me the members of a pool sorted by the score they got in a certain `week_score`.

Just to clarify

The way I get to a ceratin week score right now is
member_score = member.week_scores.find_by(week: 5).score
//member is a member of a pool

For example,

Lets say its week 5,

I want to display the week 5 score of each member of the pool sorted by the score in descending order like so,

1. David.... 30pts
2. John..... 28pts
3. Josh..... 28pts
4. Mike..... 21pts
   ...so on

what would be the query i need to achieve this? Ive tried joins but it wont work but im new at this so im pretty sure this is easy to do Im just too newb to know.

Also.. I want to read more about databases and sql for rails so I get more familiar with this. Anyone care to recommend a book?

Comment: Hi. Questions asking for code meeting a specification or for outside resources are not valid SO questions. Please read & act on [ask],  [mcve] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. When you edit to include your cut & paste & runnable MCVE include what parts of your problem you are able to solve & especially a clear specification of what the query is supposed to return. The latter because examples are only for guessing & because the way problems get solved is by clear expression & thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
week5 = Pool.first.memberships.includes(:week_scores)
       .where(:week_scores => {week: 5}).order('week_scores.score DESC')

week5.each do |membership|
  puts "#{membership.member_name}: #{membership.week_scores.first.score}"
end
```

Comment: We discourage code-only answers here. Pease include in your post how and why it answers the question.